# Issue posting form to php with materialize framework

Tags: php, forms, form-submit, materialize

The following script displays a login form. I am supposed to get back the post values in the submit script, but nothing happens. Any idea what i am doing wrong?

this form is based on this materialize [template](http://demo.geekslabs.com/materialize-v1.0/user-login.html)

I first tried to post it through ajax, but i failed. I cannot even get my $_post back on the submit.php page.

```
    <head>
      <title>Login Page</title>
      <link rel="icon" href="images/favicon/favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32">
      <!-- Favicons-->         
      <link href="css/themes/fixed-menu/materialize.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="css/themes/fixed-menu/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="css/layouts/page-center.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
      <!-- INCLUDED PLUGIN CSS ON THIS PAGE -->         
      <link href="vendors/perfect-scrollbar/perfect-scrollbar.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
   </head>
   <body class="cyan">
      <div id="login-page" class="row">
         <div class="col s12 z-depth-4 card-panel">
            <form class="login-form" action "submit.php" method="post" id="login-form">
               <div class="row">
                  <div class="input-field col s12 center">
                     <img src="images/logo/login-logo.png" alt="" class="circle responsive-img valign profile-image-login"> 
                     <p class="center login-form-text">Login</p>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="row margin">
                  <div class="input-field col s12"> 
                     <i class="material-icons prefix pt-5">person_outline</i> 
                     <input name="user_email" id="user_email" type="text"> 
                     <label for="user_email" class="center-align">Username</label>                             
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="row margin">
                  <div class="input-field col s12"> 
                     <i class="material-icons prefix pt-5">lock_outline</i> 
                     <input id="password" name="password" type="password"> 
                     <label for="password">Password</label>                             
                  </div>
                  <div id="error"></div>
               </div>
               <div class="row">
                  <div class="col s12 m12 l12 ml-2 mt-3"> 
                     <input type="checkbox" id="remember-me" /> 
                     <label for="remember-me">Remember me</label>                             
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="row">
                  <div class="input-field col s12"> 
                     <button type="submit" class="waves-effect waves-light btn gradient-45deg-green-teal z-depth-4 col s12" name="btn-login" id="btn-login">
                     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> &nbsp; Sign In
                     </button> 
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="row">
                  <div class="input-field col s6 m6 l6">
                     <p class="margin medium-small"></p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="input-field col s6 m6 l6">
                     <p class="margin right-align medium-small"></p>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </form>
         </div>
      </div>
      <!--materialize js-->   
      <script type="text/javascript" src="vendors/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>       
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/materialize.min.js"></script>         
      <!--scrollbar-->         
      <script type="text/javascript" src="vendors/perfect-scrollbar/perfect-scrollbar.min.js"></script>                
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins.js"></script>         
     </script>         
   </body>
```

Comment: So, where is your javascript, where is your php? Or we should imagine it?

Comment: OP forgot the `=` after the `action` attribute. Nothing to see here. :(

Answer (score 1):

change yout form tag `action "submit.php"`to `action="submit.php"`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18065825)

Comment: iam sorry, but i think this just simple answer to simple question

Comment: Thanks Rohan! Your answer will surely solve my problem!